# malloc and size_t seems not match

Tags: c, malloc, size-t

When I use

```
  fstat(fileno(file), &st); //struct stat st

  buf = malloc(fsize);   //size_t fsize

  fread(buf, 1, fsize, file);
```

I'm really in doubt, because `malloc` should alloc like `fsize * sizeof(size_t)` large space for me, but when I tried to visit like `buf + 8*fsize`, and I'm out of bounds.

though, the `buf+fsize` is in the correct place, end of file, and I just calculated the address, they all much!!! like malloc just returns me `fsize * sizeof(char)` large space for me.

So, where am I wrong, any help is appriciated.

Comment: "*malloc should alloc like "fsize * sizeof(size_t)*" - no it shouldn't.  If you want it to do that, you need to tell it: `buf = malloc(fsize * sizeof(size_t));`.

Comment: explain us better why you expect malloc would allocate `fsize * sizeof(size_t)` bytes. Then, if `buf+fsize` points to the end of file (one byte beyond the last byte), what do you expect to read with `buf + 8*fsize`? `malloc(fsize)` allocs `fsize` "bytes", no more.

Comment: How is `buf` declared? And what, exactly, does `size_t` have to do with anything?

Comment: Do you mean  `buf = malloc(st.st_size)`?

Comment: because malloc's prototype: "void * malloc(size_t size)"

Comment: That just means that you tell `malloc` how many bytes to allocate by passing it a `size_t` containing that number of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code says `malloc(fsize)` but what you want is `malloc(fsize * sizeof(size_t))`. The `malloc` function takes the number of bytes to allocate. It has no way to know that you are going to use the memory to store `size_t`'s.

**Update**: I may have misunderstood the question. I'll update this answer when the questioner answers the questions posed in my comment above.

Comment: I think OP is confused and I'm not sure you've contributed to clearing up this confusion. There seems to be no reason to want `fsize * sizeof(size_t)` storage here...

Comment: You could be right. I'll ask the OP some questions to clarify in a comment to the question.

Comment: It turns out every address takes 8 bytes in memory, I checked that afterwards. but thanks anyway.